# Is there already something in python or numpy to determine a number's format?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to determine if a string is a plain int, a plain float, a float using `e`, or not parsable as a number. Here's what I came up with, but this feels like something that probably already exists, perhaps in numpy? I did a brief scan of the libraries and google and didn't see anything, is this already a thing and I'm just not seeing it?

```
PLAIN_INT, PLAIN_FLOAT, E_FLOAT, STRING = range(4)

# should be just optionally - then numbers
sample_plain_ints = ['1', '0', '-5', '333333333']
# need to contain a dot
plain_floats = ['1.0', '-5.0', '-33.212', '0.0', '-1.', '-3.']
# do not need to contain a dot
e_floats = ['1.3e5', '-1.2e5', '0.0e0', '5e-3', '3e23', '3E5', '-3E-12']
# other
strings = ['aether', '1ee3', 'buzz', 'eeep', '121212beep']


def determine_str_type(item):
    try:
        float(item)
        try:
            int(item)
            return PLAIN_INT
        except ValueError:
            return E_FLOAT if 'E' in item.upper() else PLAIN_FLOAT
    except ValueError:
        return STRING


assert all([determine_str_type(item) == PLAIN_INT for item in sample_plain_ints])
assert all([determine_str_type(item) == PLAIN_FLOAT for item in plain_floats])
assert all([determine_str_type(item) == E_FLOAT for item in e_floats])
assert all([determine_str_type(item) == STRING for item in strings])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a regex for that (`(-?\d+)(\.\d*)?([eE]-?\d+)?$`), capture the different parts and decide depending on the output:

```
import re

lst = ['1', '0', '-5', '333333333', '1.0', '-5.0', '-33.212', '0.0', '-1.', '-3.', '1.3e5', '-1.2e5', '0.0e0', '5e-3', '3e23', '3E5', '-3E-12', 'aether', '1ee3', 'buzz', 'eeep', '121212beep']

def determine_str_type(s):
    pat = re.compile(r'(-?\d+)(\.\d*)?([eE]-?\d+)?$')
    match m.groups() if (m:=pat.match(s)) else None:
        case None:
            return 'STRING '
        case (_, None, None):
            return 'PLAIN_INT'
        case (_, _, None):
            return 'PLAIN_FLOAT'
        case (_, _, _):
            return 'E_FLOAT'
        
for s in lst:
    print(f'{s: <11}: {determine_str_type(s)}')
```

Output:

```
1          : PLAIN_INT
0          : PLAIN_INT
-5         : PLAIN_INT
333333333  : PLAIN_INT
1.0        : PLAIN_FLOAT
-5.0       : PLAIN_FLOAT
-33.212    : PLAIN_FLOAT
0.0        : PLAIN_FLOAT
-1.        : PLAIN_FLOAT
-3.        : PLAIN_FLOAT
1.3e5      : E_FLOAT
-1.2e5     : E_FLOAT
0.0e0      : E_FLOAT
5e-3       : E_FLOAT
3e23       : E_FLOAT
3E5        : E_FLOAT
-3E-12     : E_FLOAT
aether     : STRING 
1ee3       : STRING 
buzz       : STRING 
eeep       : STRING 
121212beep : STRING
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J41gmM/1)

Comment: I like that, that's clever